# How do I set the prefetch limit for NMS listener container

Tags: activemq-classic, nms

Other than on the connection URL, how do I set the prefetch limit in spring config. I can't find any doc on any of the properties and the param on the Connection URL doesn't seem to work. Besides, I need to do this on the consumer level. Here is my config below.

```
   <nms:listener-container 
    connection-factory="SingleConnectionFactory" 
    concurrency="${GraphManagerService.NMS.Consumers}"
    auto-startup="false">
    <nms:listener ref="MessageListenerAdapter" destination="${GraphManagerService.NMS.QueueName}" />
   </nms:listener-container>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this on a per-consumer basis you add the option to the destination.

> myQueue?consumer.prefetchSize=10