# NMS ActiveMQ Ignores Prefetch Limit set in Code

Tags: c#, performance, activemq-classic, nms

I'm using the current Apache.NMS 1.7.1 and Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ 1.7.2.
I'm using `IndividualAcknowledge`, so I'm trying to keep the number of loaded messages quite low, because it get's really slow if I have >>1000 messages loaded without Acking them (It's searching a linked list of all messages each time).

I have the following codesnippets:

```
BlockingCollection<IMessage> _collection = new BlockingCollection<IMessage>();
var factory = new ConnectionFactory("activemq:tcp://localhost:61616");
var _connection = (Connection) factory.CreateConnection();
_connection.PrefetchPolicy.All = 1000;
var session = (Session) _connection.CreateSession(AcknowledgementMode.IndividualAcknowledge);
var destination = SessionUtil.GetDestination(session, "queue://testQueue");
var messageConsumer = (MessageConsumer)session.CreateConsumer(destination);
messageConsumer.Listener += message => _collection.Add(message);
_connection.Start();
```

The queue `testQueue` contains >>20_000 messages. After waiting some seconds, `_collection` contains all the messages, without me acknowledging any of them.

If I understand [the dokumentation](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html) right, I should get at most 1000 until I start acknowledging them.

> Once the broker has dispatched a prefetch limit number of messages to a consumer it will not dispatch any more messages to that consumer until the consumer has acknowledged at least 50% of the prefetched messages, e.g., prefetch/2, that it received. When the broker has received said acknowledgements it will dispatch a further prefetch/2 number of messages to the consumer to 'top-up', as it were, its prefetch buffer.

I also tried some variations like only setting `QueuePrefetch` [or setting the policy in the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311148/apache-nms-activemq-connectionfactory-ignores-prefetch-set-in-broker-url):

```
activemq:tcp://localhost:61616?nms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=100
```

or [in the queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956159/how-do-i-set-the-prefetch-limit-for-nms-listener-container):

```
queue://testQueue?consumer.prefetchSize=100
```

Regarding the slowness of the `IndividualAcknowledge`, I already tried several other options without much luck:

```
messageConsumer.OptimizeAcknowledge = true;
messageConsumer.OptimizeAcknowledgeTimeOut = 1000;
messageConsumer.OptimizedAckScheduledAckInterval = 500;
```

Though I'm not completely clear about the differences of the last to options.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using an asynchronous listener the broker will be given sending you everything as the client continues to grant credit to the broker on delivery of each message to your asynchronous event listener.  To truly limit the amount of messages deliver to the client at any given time the client needs to use synchronous receive calls.  Individual acknowledge is best paired with synchronous consumption such that you can control how many messages are read and acknowledge them at some point in time when ready.

The optimized acknowledge settings don't apply in individual acknowledge mode so that won't help with performance.